# Wrong query evaluation with aggregation subquery

Tags: sparql, graphdb

Please refer to [Factforge Endpoint](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=false&sameAs=false&query=SELECT+%0A%3FmyVar+%3Fp+%3Fo%0AWHERE+%0A%7B+++%0A++%7B+%0A++++SELECT+%3FmyVar+%0A++++++++WHERE+%7B+%0A++++++++++++%3FmyVar+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FarbitraryNonExistent%3E+%3Fxx.+%0A++++++++%7D+%0A++++GROUP+BY+%3FmyVar%0A++%7D+%0A++%3FmyVar+%3Fp+%3Fo.++%0A%7D+%0ALIMIT+10) to execute this query. The subquery doesn't return any results. `?myVar` will be projected out to the containing query, and then joined with the triple pattern `?myVar ?p ?o.`. But as there are no results from the inner select, the join should result in nothing. However, this is not the case when executing the query. Isn't this a bug?

```
SELECT 
?myVar ?p ?o
WHERE 
{   
  { 
    SELECT ?myVar 
        WHERE { 
            ?myVar <http://www.example.com/arbitraryNonExistent> ?xx. 
        } 
    GROUP BY ?myVar
  } 
  ?myVar ?p ?o.  
} 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It's a bug for sure. Are you doing experiments with sub-queries or why are you always running arbitrary queries? By the way, you already recognized last time that the wikidata thing also didn'T work for your local GraphDB instance - FactForge is also backed by GraphDB ... as usual, contact the GraphDB devs such that it can be fixed (if not already done - don't know the GraphDB version used by FactForge)

Comment: I contacted GraphDB. The queries I post look arbitrary because they are a simplified reproduction of the problem happening at the original queries I have against the data I locally use. And yes, basically aggregation subqueries are a thing I am using.

Comment: Try to remove `GROUP BY ?myVar` from the subquery, use `DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: I need the GROUP BY in the aggregation query. This is a simplified version of my basic query which contains aggregate functions. However, adding `HAVING (COUNT (*) > 0)` after the `GROUP BY` does the job. But still there is something wrong there.

Comment: BTW, results of the inner subquery are also different in GraphDB and e.g. Blazegraph. `HAVING (bound(?myVar))` would be more natural than  `HAVING (COUNT(*) > 0)` :-).

Comment: To be honest, I'm wondering what's going wrong here with the triple stores. Year 2018, and we have at least two triple stores that fail with a simple sub-query

Comment: I think the accepted solution was wrong.  This case only happens when there is only one group (which is the case when one does not use a GROUP BY statement but though aggregates, which will cause an automatic creation of a single group that is empty - not the case in my query!). If you try my query in the current GraphDB implementation, the results are just as normal as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It is the expected behaviour. According to https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregateAlgebra if there is a GROUP BY:

```
Group(exprlist, Ω) = { ... | μ in Ω }
```

and we have no matches, then Ω is empty, so:

```
Group(exprlist, {}) = {}
```

The effect is that the subquery returns a single solution where ?myVar is unbound and the join with the next statement pattern matches everything for ?myVar. At the end you are getting a lot of solutions for the whole query.

There is even a W3C SPARQL conformance testcase covering the exact scenario:

- https://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/docs/tests/data-sparql11/aggregates/agg-empty-group.rq
- https://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/docs/tests/data-sparql11/aggregates/agg-empty-group.srx

And also an old discussion at [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17410/semantics-of-sparql-aggregates](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109081257/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/17410/semantics-of-sparql-aggregates).

Comment: Looks like this was wrong. This case only happens when there is only one group (which is the case when one does not use a GROUP BY statement but though aggregates, which will cause an automatic creation of a single group that is empty - not the case in my query!). If you try my query in the current GraphDB implementation, the results are just as normal as expected.