# SPARQL aggregate behaviour when no pre-aggregated results

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, graph-theory

I'm surprised at the behaviour of SPARQL aggregate when there are zero results being aggregated.

When there are 1+ results (before aggregation) then everything works as I would expect and the same as what I would get in SQL. If there are 0 results though, I get a response which contains a single empty binding `[{}]` when what I would have expected was no results at all `[]`. This caught me out as in SQL, this would have resulted in zero rows.

1. I can't seem to find any information about why this is the case, so if anyone can point me at some that would be useful.
2. Adding a `HAVING` clause requiring at least one result in my `group by` field is the best solution?

An example:

Data:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>
INSERT DATA {
    d:a rdf:type :User ;
        :name "bob" ;
        :val 1 .
    d:b rdf:type :User ;
        :name "bill" ;
        :val 1 .
    d:d rdf:type :User ;
        :name "ben" ;
        :val 2 .
}
```

If I do this query I get the expected results because there are results, pre aggregation:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>
SELECT ?val (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?name) AS ?names)
WHERE {
    ?user rdf:type :User ;
          :name ?name ;
          :val ?val .
}
GROUP BY ?val
```

Results:

```
{
    'head': {
        'vars': ['val', 'names']
    },
    'results': {
        'bindings': [
            {
                'val': {
                    'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
                    'type': 'literal',
                    'value': '1'
                },
                'names': {
                    'type': 'literal',
                    'value':
                    'bob bill'
                }
            },
            {
                'val': {
                    'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
                    'type': 'literal',
                    'value': '2'
                },
                'names': {
                    'type': 'literal',
                    'value': 'ben'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, if I was to add a clause that was looking for `val` of 3 then there are zero results pre-aggregation.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>
SELECT ?val (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?name) AS ?names)
WHERE {
    BIND (3 AS ?val)
    ?user rdf:type :User ;
          :name ?name ;
          :val ?val .
}
GROUP BY ?val
```

Result:

```
{
    'head': {
        'vars': ['val', 'names']
    },
    'results': {
        'bindings': [
            {
                'names': {
                    'type': 'literal',
                    'value': ''
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is not what I was expecting.

I can workaround this by using `HAVING`, but I am wondering why that is necessary?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://schema#>
PREFIX d: <http://data#>
SELECT ?val (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?name) AS ?names)
WHERE {
    BIND (3 AS ?val)
    ?user rdf:type :User ;
          :name ?name ;
          :val ?val .
}
GROUP BY ?val
HAVING(COUNT(?val) > 0)
```

Results:

```
{
    'head': {
        'vars': ['val', 'names']
    },
    'results': {
        'bindings': []
    }
}
```

Comment: Related? — https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116255/7879193

Comment: Great thanks. This one was tough to search for.